# SimpleSamlPhp IDP calling another IDP (IDP Proxy)

Tags: saml-2.0, simplesamlphp

I have a situation where I simpleSamlPhp as an IDP, in some cases I want to handle a Authentication Request myself. In other cases I want to farm the request off to another IDP (depending on the state of a cookie). This IDP can talk directly to the SP if need be.

I can write a custom authentication module. What I am not sure about is the best way to push the saml request to the third party in the cases that I don't want to handle it myself.

I have seen some posts about IDP proxying, is that what I am trying to do?

In the worst case I can manually create an Authentication Request and send it to the other IDP but it feels like there should be a better way.

Is there a better way than manually creating an authentication request?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of options, and it really depends on the capabilities of the SP you are logging into. If it supports multiple IdPs then go with discovery, otherwise go with proxying.

## Discovery

If the service provider supports multiple IDPs or Discovery (which is where the user picks the correct IdP) then you can just configure the SP that way. This is a common setup in identity federations.

The discovery page can live externally to the SP (this is a feature in both `simplesamlphp` and `shibboleth`, and probably others). You could customize the discovery to auto select the correct idp if the cookie is present. The discovery protocol allows you to tell the SP which IdP to initiate the log in with.

## Proxying

In proxying your IdP (IdP-A) is an SP for the other IdP (IdP-B). In this case you create an SP in your `authsources` file and make your Idp use that. In this scenario IdP-A generates its own SAML assertions and the original SP only is aware of IdP-A. This is a common setup where an SP can only know about a single IdP, and in hub and spoke identity federations.

Answer (score 1):

Proxying as Patrick suggested was what I wanted. It is known as 'IdP Proxy'.

I was a little stuck as how to implement this with simplesamlphp, so I'm posting my solution for posterity.

You need to define the second IdP as you would normally in your Simple saml config.

You also need to define your host IdP as you would normally and create a custom auth source as described [here](https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/1.11/simplesamlphp-customauth#section_1). However, you don't need to implement an extension of `SimpleSAML_Auth_Source` rather than `sspmod_core_Auth_UserPassBase`.

Then you should put the following code in your class

```
 public function authenticate(&$state) {
    // Custom logic here to choose IDP
    $authId = 'proxy_test_idp'; // or whatever the id of IDP you need to proxy to is.
    $as = SimpleSAML_Auth_Source::getById($authId);
    $as->authenticate($state);
  }
```

The code in the [multi auth module](https://github.com/simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp/blob/2d06c575a95f5d966d79c5525b28bf71174899c4/modules/multiauth/lib/Auth/Source/MultiAuth.php) included with simplesamlphp shows this in more detail. Depending on your needs you may need to do more, but this is essentially a MVP of IDP proxying in simplesamlphp.